# How to return list linq in json in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
public List<Detail> GetOrderDetails()
{
    var orderDetails = (from user in db.Users
                        join detail in db.OrderDetails
                        on user.Id equals detail.UserId
                        where (detail.DateAdded != null)
                        select new Detail
                        {
                            FirstName = user.FirstName,
                            LastName = user.LastName,
                            Origin = detail.OriginCode,
                            Destination = detail.DestinationCode,
                            CarrierCode = detail.CarrierCode,
                            IsReturn = detail.IsReturn,
                            IsCancel = detail.IsCancel,
                            OrderId = detail.OrderId
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
    return Json(orderDetails);
}
```

This code gives me the following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<TravelingAdmin.Controllers.Detail>`

Answer (score 5):

**Problems:**

1. `(your query).FirstOrDefault();` returns an element not a list.
2. `Json(x)` converts x to string which contains json representation of x.

**Here are your options:**

1. You can remove `FirstOrDefault()` and use `return (your query).ToList()` if you want to return list of objects.
2. You can change the return type of method to `Detail` instead of `List<Detail>` and then use `return orderDetails;` instead of  `return Json(orderDetails);`

---

**UPDATE:**

As inferred from title of the question you want to *"return list in json in MVC Controller"*

You should change the method to this

```
public ActionResult GetOrderDetails()
{
    var orderDetails = (from user in db.Users
                        join detail in db.OrderDetails
                        on user.Id equals detail.UserId
                        where (detail.DateAdded != null)
                        select new Detail
                        {
                            FirstName = user.FirstName,
                            LastName = user.LastName,
                            Origin = detail.OriginCode,
                            Destination = detail.DestinationCode,
                            CarrierCode = detail.CarrierCode,
                            IsReturn = detail.IsReturn,
                            IsCancel = detail.IsCancel,
                            OrderId = detail.OrderId
                        }).ToList();

    return Json(orderDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` or an object. This is not a list then. It will be a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your return type to JsonResult And use .tolist() method to convert in to list  return Json(orderdetails.tolist(),jsonrequestbehaviour.allowget) it's depend on your request if you send request Through "Post" method then use [httppost] attribute on the top of method name and remove "jsonrequestbehaviour.allowget" from your code, it will work for you.